# EJB JPA QL. Need query to get data from DB by element in Collection object

Tags: select, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am facing a proble that put me in difficult situation.
I have class Article:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Articles")
    public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="article_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="a_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="a_content")
    private String content;

    @OneToMany
    @Column(name="a_tag")
    private Collection <Tags> tag;



  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Tags")
  public class Tags implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="tag_id")
  private Long tag_id;

  @Column(name="tag_name",nullable=false)
  private String tag_name;

  @Column(name="tag_descr")
  private String tag_descr;

  //position 0 - supertag
  //position 1 - subsupertag
  //position 2 - subtags
  //Collection limited to 3 elements.(3 tags at most, necessaryly Super,subsuper,subtag
  @Column(name="super_tags")
  @OneToMany
  private Collection<Tags> supertags = new ArrayList<Tags>(3);

  //0-supertag 1-subsupertag 2- subtags
  @Column(name="tag_type")
  private int tag_type;
```

My tagging system is such that I have Supertag, subsuprttag and subtag. Supertag is parent for subsupertag and subtag, subsupertag is parent for subtag.
Each article has super, subsuper and sub tags.

Now, I want to get only articles from database, that has a certain tag, but have no idea how to refere to , for example, element 2 in Collection tags (by name or position), (which would be subtag).

```
final String q = "SELECT f FROM Article f WHERE f.a_tag= ..I m lost here ...
EntityManager em;
em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

I hope my question is clear enough. I gave it my best shot)) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the tags to access them in JPQL,

see,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JOIN

As for the type of Tag, how is the type stored in the database?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Tags are mapped authomatically, not by me. I ve put a screenshot of table Articles and Tags here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51537645/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-02%20at%2009.16.37.png https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51537645/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-02%20at%2009.22.15.png , as you can see, articles_tags has  table has only article id and subtag id. I need to be able to select all article by Supertag, subsuper and subtag separately, that s why I though about joining tables. Thank you. Still struggeling with this issue.